# Angular 2 animations style function in state vs transition vs animate

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-animations

I'm very confused. What is the difference between the `style()` function inside a `state()`

```
state('inactive', style({
   backgroundColor: '#eee',
   transform: 'scale(1)'
 })),
```

and a `style()` function inside `transition()`

```
 transition('inactive => *', [
    style({ transform: 'scale3d(.3, .3, .3)' }),
    animate(100)
 ]),
```

and a `style()` function inside `animation()`

```
 animate(100, style({ transform: 'scale3d(.0, .0, .0)' }))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what the [Angular Animations documentation](https://angular.io/guide/animations) says about it :

**1. style() inside state()**

> These state definitions specify the end styles of each state. **They are
>   applied to the element once it has transitioned to that state, and
>   stay as long as it remains in that state.** In effect, you're defining
>   what styles the element has in different states.

So these styles defined inside a state are the ones before and after the animation, at some given state.

**2. style() inside transition()**

> You can also apply a **style during an animation but not keep it around
>   after the animation finishes.** You can define such styles inline, in
>   the transition.

These styles are applied only during the animation time.

**3. style() inside animate()**

> animate specifies an animation step that will **apply the provided
>   styles data for a given amount of time** based on the provided timing
>   expression value.

The styles given inside animate will take some specific time to get applied during the animation